# PHP gets EHLO for mail() function from nginx server_name - error

Tags: nginx, php, exim

I'm using nginx with regex inside virtualhost name to catch subdomain name to work with that later:

```
server_name ~^(?<subdir>(\\w|\\-)*)(\\.)?(domain\\.org)$;
```

I have discovered that the mail() function within PHP (running as FPM from nginx) does not send emails.

I looked up the exim logs and found this:

```
2019-03-27 20:51:56 rejected EHLO from [127.0.0.1]: syntactically invalid argument(s): ~^(?<subdir>(\\w|\\-)*)(\\.)?(domain\\.org)$
```

Of course, this is an invalid EHLO. It looks that PHP gets this from nginx. But I haven't found a way how to control this (besides changing virtualhost name). I'm using this configuration parameter in PHP:

```
sendmail_path="/usr/sbin/exim -t -i -f info@domain.org"
```

Disabling checks in exim is problably not a good idea though.

Thanks

Comment: I guess you use $server_name variable instead of $host somewhere in nginx config

Comment: What do you mean? My virtualhost looks like this: `server { listen 80; server_name ~^(?<subdir>(\\w|\\-)*)(\\.)?(domain\\.org)$;`  Do you suggest to replace server_name with host somehow?

Comment: Probably you have something like `fastcgi_pass Host $server_name;` somewhere

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. At the end I have added this to my nginx config and it works: `fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME       domain.org;`

Comment: Sounds like a bug in your PHP application. You should report it to the developer(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to explicitly set SERVER_NAME in nginx config:

`fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME domain.org;`